# user lookup field for external lists

Tags: lookup-column, external-content-type, external-list, bdc-model

Guys please don't beat me too much, I want to add user lookup field into my external content type to use sharepoint people picker in my external list, the price doesn't stand up. So is it ever possible in Sharepoint 2013 and how?